# Android Room insertAll issues

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm starting using Android Room and I'm having some troubles.

I have an ArrayList of 7 Orders and when I call insertAll(List orders)
only 4 orders are inserted into the database.

How can I debug the insert query in order to find what is blocking ?

Thanks

Comment: Has your order table have any primary key? if so, what option have you selected for when there is conflict in the data?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I do have a primary key and I've choosen OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE
So it's doing the 7 inserts but when I get all orders inserted the getAll() method returns only 4 of them...

Comment: That is odd... it must be a simple Query like "SELECT * FROM orders" can you put your DAO and your entity/pojo in the question?

Comment: @Dao
public interface OrderDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public long insertOrder(Order order);
 
 @Query("SELECT * FROM orders")
    List<Order> getAll();
}

Comment: @Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
public class Order {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "orders";

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("order_number")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_number")
    private String orderNumber;
 
}
// Call
for (int i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++) {
 long lastInsertId = mDb.getOrderDao().insertOrder(orders.get(i));
 Log.d(TAG, "Order ID = " + lastInsertId);
}
List<Order> myOrders = mDb.getOrderDao().getAll();

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The calls done by Room are not synchronous so probably when you perform

```
List<Order> myOrders = mDb.getOrderDao().getAll()
```

it is still inserting the orders.

Try this

```
@Dao 
public interface OrderDao { 
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) 
    public long insertOrder(Order order); 

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) 
    void insertAllOrders(List<Order> order); 

    @Query("SELECT * FROM orders") 
    List<Order> getAll(); 
 }

@Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME) 
public class Order { 
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "orders"; 
   @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
   private int id; 
   @SerializedName("order_number") 
   @ColumnInfo(name = "order_number") 
   private String orderNumber; 
} 

// Call 
mDb.getOrderDao().insertAllOrders(orders);
Log.d(TAG, "inserted all");

Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

             List<Order> myOrders = mDb.getOrderDao().getAll();
             Log.d(TAG, "Orders nr = " + myOrders.size()); 
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked !
If I have to chain multiple queries what is the proper way to do it ?

Comment: Well that is a good question. I am also still new to Room but I think that if you perform the calls using executor then it should work but I don't guaranteed it. But I don't think you will ever need to perform more than two consecutive calls to the DB

Comment: that is not true.
room inserts are sync so when insertAll returns, all data will be inserted.
and also, even if you try to read that data from another thread, you never ever receive partial data.

insert(List<>)'s are automatically put inside a transaction so any other parallel query can either see db right before all those are inserted or after all of them are inserted.

Comment: @Yigit: please write your comment as an answer so that people can easily see that.  However, since insert(List<>) is done in one transaction, How this answer solves the problem Jerome is having.

Comment: Im having issues seeing how this solves the issue. If `insertAllOrders()` is async, how does creating `newSingleThreadExecutor()` after calling `insertAll()` maintain single thread execution? `InsertAll()` can return before completing still. Don't you have to at least place both `insertAllOrders()`  and  `getAll()` inside the `execute(){ }` block ?

Answer (score 8):

OnConflict Property must be added.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```